# Connect multiple DC Fans Together

Tags: chassis, fan

How can you mechanically secure multiple DC fans together to form a fan array?

I would like to create a 4x2 array of 120mm DC fans using Sunon MEC0251V3-000U-A99 (120mm x 120mm x 25mm). I tried 3d printing 8 fan housings and solvent welding them together but it's trickier than it seems.

If there are some 80/20 T-slots aluminium extrusions avaliable, would this be possible using them?

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0):

There are infinite ways to do this; there isn't really a "right" or "more appropriate" solution unless you can expound on what exactly it is you're using the fan array for, if you want to be able to move it around, etc.

If you have access to a 3-D printer I would suggest making tiny little square plates with 4 bolt-sized holes, sized so that when centered at the mutual corners of 4 fans (the center of a 2x2), the holes line up with the fan's mounting holes, and use 6 of them (3 to each side of the 4x2 array) with 12 bolts to secure them, which should secure them together, but obviously won't provide extensive rigidity.

If you have 80/20 T-slot lying around, sure, you could rig something with that. If memory serves correctly, the mounting holes in 120mm fans tend to be just big enough for 1/4" bolts, which means they'll fit into 80/20 T-nuts just fine. You'll want to come up with some kind of frame to mount the fans on, but keep in mind that 80/20 is a fairly bulky and heavy material, so that the more of it, the more cumbersome the design will be.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It'll be something that holds the 8 fans together so they can be moved/positioned as one single object rather than 8 individual fans. Wonder if there exist bolts and plates such that a bolt on each fan can be connected to each other using the plate.

Comment: Well, you could always use U-bolts and lace the fans vertically along the center line and horizontally along the edges.